# Streaming polyline while adding records to related tables in ArcPad

Tags: arcpad, events

I'm designing an ArcPad solution for our field staff; we collect point data and use lines to identify the amount of 'effort' (and to maintain accountability).

While collecting a 'streaming polyline' (Add verticies continuously from GPS) as our field staff's "track" (daily effort) we need to also collect point data along the way.

Every time you collect add a record to a point feature class in a related table in the poly-line streaming stops.  This forces our staff to manually turn the polyline streaming back on for every record they collect.  Human error is just about guaranteed over the course of editing 50 points in a day.

I know that event handling is built into ArcPad through ArcPad Studio, but I haven't had any luck triggering the polyline streaming with the onOK event of related table's form.

Any help putting together an event handler would be appreciated.  The help files aren't nearly as useful as the Python sample code associated with ArcMap on the desktop.  Here's a quick look at the direction I've been leaning. I'm not fully sure how to even compose a full even handling script for ArcPad.

> From help files:   'gpsstream' => Add Vertices continuously from GPS
>
> **Form (onOk event):**
>
> **Application.ExecuteCommand("gpsstream")**

Answer (score 2):

Rather than coding a solution, have you considered using the [GPS Tracklog](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcpad/10.0/help/index.html#//00s100000100000000) instead of a streaming polyline?

The tracklog saves at a defined interval GPS coordinates provided the GPS is on and receiving in a shapfile and displays it in ArcPad. However it is not an edit feature, so it does not stop when yuo add a new record to your edit feature (such as your point feature class).

As a bonus the tracklog saves a bunch of GPS information, including height, time, gps fix quality, etc, which should come in handy through your auditing process.

Comment: In fact, that is our current work around that we're trying to move away from.  In order to conduct more than one survey you have to manually create a new shapefile in the tracklog.

The main reason we're trying to move away from this method is the amount of post processing required to reach our desired result.  As you mentioned, you cannot edit attribute information on the tracklog.shp.  I'd have to write a script that converts each tracklog into a line and  then edit the attributes of those features.  

With 15 field staff & potentially multiple tracks in a day - we'd like to avoid this.